Android Epoxy RecyclerView (airbnb) -> view flicker when request rebuild
When a single item of data changes, I initiate an epoxy request to rebuild the entire view, resulting in view flickering
I want only the updated view to be refreshed when rebuilding it to update view data
(android, epoxy, java)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

here are some solutions -

give static(should be unique) id to viewHolder (id must remain same for viewHolder)
removing Item default animation can also help

